# c program doesn't takes "space" as input to show the acsii code

Tags: c

The program shows output for all other characters instead of space. When I enter "space" it doesn't do anything and just waits.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    while(true){
        printf("Enter character:");
        scanf("\n%c", &c);
        if (c == 27 )break;
        printf("ascii value:%d\n", c);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for all other character comes fine.

```
Enter character:r
ascii value:114
Enter character:e
ascii value:101
Enter character:c
ascii value:99
Enter character:p
ascii value:112
Enter character:^[
```

I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: Did you try the format string `"%c"` for `scanf()`? However, if you just want to input single characters, other functions like `fgetc()` and friends are better choices.

Comment: to read control characters you need to put your terminal in raw mode.

Comment: @thebusybee "%c" was actually causing the problem. "%c" was trying to read the character from the buffer and was showing the ascii code of "enter" i.e 10 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I enter "space" it doesn't do anything and just waits.

`scanf("\n%c", &c);` does not mean read a line-feed, then a character.
Instead `"\n%c"` means to read any number of white-spaces like `'\n'`, space, tab, .... and then read a character.

OP's code is stuck reading white-spaces.

Instead, read a *line*.  Below has minimal testing and only pays attention to the first `char` in a *line* of input.

```
// scanf("\n%c", &c);
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Input is closed\n");
  return -1;
}
c = buf[0];
```

Remember the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a `char` too.

---

To read the *escape* character, other input functions may be needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can read `Esc` via `fgets` (refering to `if (c == 27 ) ...`) . At least on Windows it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am confident `fgets()` will work as well as `scanf("\n%c", &c);` to read an escape character.  Yet I suspect your are correct in that neither work and OP needs an implementation specific input function.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, I had to write a function that clears the buffer after reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void clear_buffer(){
    char ch;
    while(1){
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF ) break;
    }
}

int main(){
    char c;
   
    while(1){
        printf("Enter character:");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == 27 )break;
        printf("ascii value:%d\n", c);
        clear_buffer();
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The function `clear_buffer` clears the buffer(enter character gets cleared) so that only the first character is accepted and none of the other characters after that.